# Do (a+b)/ab & ab/(a+b) have definite names?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Do (a+b)/ab & ab/(a+b) have definite names? Do any theorems or theories mention these terms? They are usually seen.

Comment: $\frac{a+b}{ab}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$ is called the sum of reciprocals.

Comment: The other one is half the harmonic mean... do your really need names for these expressions... I would suggest no.

Comment: The second expression is also called the reciprocal of the sum of the reciprocals. The expression is used in focal length problems and crossed ladder problems, as well as some others.